# How to have separate scaling for two monitors on Pop! OS

Tags: multi-monitor, pop-os

I'm brand new to Linux, and I have installed Pop! OS to replace my Windows installation. Enjoying it so far, but having some troubles with high-res monitor scaling.

My first monitor is 3440x1440 (21:9 ultrawide) resolution, and my other monitor is 3840:2160(4k). I want to have the ultrawide monitor be scaled to 100%, but I want the 4k monitor to be scaled to somewhere around 150%-200%.

I noticed that in the display settings, I can turn on the fractional scaling, and set scaling separately that way, but when I do so, there is some weird behavior. I noticed that in games, I could set my resolution to 6880x2880. So after messing around, it seems like if I do the fractional scaling, it increases the size of my main monitor, which I do not want to happen, because then gaming is much more difficult performance-wise.

So, I want a way that I can have separate scaling between the two that doesn't involve fractional scaling. More over, I tried to use an xrandr command that I found online, and it basically completely broke everything, and made both of my screens act crazy, and I had to reboot. So I'm not super sure that will work either.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't have a solution but I'm just chiming in to say that you're not alone. I too have problems with Pop_OS! monitor resolutions. It's been an issue for the 4 years I've had this laptop and I regret getting a hidpi display. I figure out a solution, then an update breaks that solution. Very frustrating.

Comment: Are you using nvidia? I read somewhere that xrandr doesn't support the language that nvidia speaks... So instead of xrandr, nvidia-settings must be used to make changes to the displays.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using nvidia, here's an example of what I have used in the past to get a consistent and visible display across my 3 monitors which have different native resolutions. I set this as a startup application which runs after I log in.

[image: Startup application to set the resolution]

```
sh -c '/usr/bin/nvidia-settings --assign CurrentMetaMode="HDMI-0: nvidia-auto-select +1920+0, DP-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0 {viewportin=1920x1080}, DP-2: nvidia-auto-select +3840+0"; gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor 1.0'
```

To get those settings, I use `nvidia-settings --query=CurrentMetaMode` as a starting point.